# JNI Set String Field

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I try to work with structure between C and Java.
For this I created a Java class:

```
public class DriveInfo {
    public String val1;
    public String val2;
    public String val3;
}
```

This I used inside a Java function:

```
    private void getDriveInfos() {
        DriveInfo newInfo = new DriveInfo();
        newInfo.val1 = "Test";
        getDriveInfo(newInfo);
        logModel.add(logModel.getSize(), newInfo.val1);
    }
```

The getDriveInfo is declared in JNI Interface with:

```
private native int getDriveInfo(DriveInfo mClass);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNIViie_getDriveInfo
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject job, jobject jStruct);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNIViie_getDriveInfo
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jobject jStruct){

    jclass clazz;
    jfieldID fid;
    jstring buffer = env->NewStringUTF("myname");

    clazz = env->GetObjectClass(jStruct);
    fid = env->GetFieldID(clazz,"val1","Ljava/lang/String;");
    if(clazz == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    env->SetObjectField(clazz,fid,buffer);


    return 0;

}
```

I expected that the `getDriveInfo` function will print out `"myname"` not `"test"`.
My question is now, what I have done wrong so that the `val1` do not contain the `"myname"` string?

Comment: What is `objRet` in this line: `env->SetObjectField(objRet,fid,buffer);`? It looks like you are setting the field on the wrong object. I think it should be `jStruct`.

Comment: Also, while perhaps not related to your problem, `jStruct` is a `jobject`, not a `jclass`.

Comment: You could try passing by value instead of by reference

Comment: Iam really sorry, some artefacts were still inside the function. I have updated this now.

Comment: Why are yoiu setting the field in the class when the field isn't static? You should be setting it in the object. Your code is lacking in error-checking, which would have exposed this with an exception. You are also checking for `clazz == null` in the wrong place, not that you need `clazz` at all, and you are not checking `fid == 0` at all, or the result of `setObjectField()` either.

Comment: @luckyging3r There is no passing by reference here.

Comment: @user207421 `clazz` is still needed for `GetFieldID`.

Comment: Ok, I have changd it to static and no it works well. Thank you for that hint

Comment: Why? Do you really want it to be static? I doubt it. Did someone recommend you do that? Not me. What *I* recommended was to set it in the object. Making things `static` is a design decision, not a debugging technique.

Comment: @user207421 I think it was your answer that the field is not static. In my eyes I have everything done to change the filed inside the object. I created an object, pass the object but the object value was not set. I did not get any other answer what is wrong at my code?

Comment: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo079